# Treeview, Listview and Datagridview: Hiding the file path

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, treeview

In this example:

1. picture select
2. select folder (show Treeview)
3. select excelfile (show Listview)
4. select in Listview excelfile
5. Click and show in Gridview my excel file.

[image]

I'm asking how hide the file path...

This is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private object datagridview;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ids = Directory .GetLogicalDrives();
            foreach (string id in ids)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(id);

            }
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Clear();

            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
            foreach(string dir in dirs)

            {
                listView1.Items.Add(dir, 0);
                treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(dir);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My korean is a lot worse than your english, but I will try to help.

I am having to guess a little about what you are trying to do, but what I think you want, is to display an excel file in the DataGridView, but double clicking the file in the listView?

Firstly you need to add excel files to your List view.

I did this by altering your treeView1_AfterSelect to:

```
        listView1.Clear();

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text, "*.xls*");
        foreach (string dir in dirs)

        {
            listView1.Items.Add(dir, 0);
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(dir);
        }
        foreach (string file in files)

        {
            listView1.Items.Add(file, 0);
        }
```

Note the addition of the GetFiles.

I then added a DoubleClick Event to the ListView:

```
    private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        if (fileName.Contains(".xl"))
        {
            string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            fileName +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
```

For this to work you need to have the correct ACE.OLEDB provider.  For some reason that I cannot explain, although my system is 64-bit and I have Office 64 Bit, I needed to install the 32-bit Access runtime, to get this to work.  I give the link here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: You are my hero. Although not yet in accordance with , to understand my intentions according to the so grateful . Full wish good luck!!1

Comment: You 've said all day  but, dataGridview1 not show xls.  Is there something I need to change ?

Comment: Offset the excelfile in the listview gridview and not Modified

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. Do you get an error message when you try to open the xls? Please note that the above code tries to open Sheet1 of the xls. If you do not have a Sheet1 this will be a problem.

Comment: Can I change name to sheet1 to another ? For example, block 1$ block $ 2 $ 3 $ Block?Perhaps I will give thanks to your site as a reference .

Comment: It does not appear in the DataGridView.ㅠㅠ